# What is the difference between getting messages over a looped kafka consumer and manually calling poll?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, polling

I'm using [Kafka Python](https://pypi.org/project/kafka-python/) to fetch data from a topic and feed it into Elastic Search.

From my knowledge, there are 2 ways of polling data:

1. Using a loop on the consumer

```
for message in consumer:
   // Process your message 
   ...
   ..
```

2. Call poll at periodic intervals:

```
while (repeat at some interval):
   messages = consumer.poll()
   // Process your message 
   ...
   ..
```

These lead me to the following questions:

1. How does option 1 work internally? (Calling poll, commit etc)
2. Will option 2 be less resource-intensive since `poll()` is being called periodically?

Answer (score 0):

> fetch data from a topic and feed it into Elastic Search

First, don't use Python or manual consumers for this - Use Kafka Connect framework, which has better fault tolerance and scalablility constraints.

---

> How does option 1 work internally

You can read the [source code](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) and find out ;)

[`poll` will be called internally](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/consumer/group.py#L1116-L1131), between processing each batch, assuming the python api does pre-fetching

> Will option 2 be less resource-intensive

You need to consider that **not** calling poll will cause the consumer group to rebalance, and therefore take resources on its own to perform that action.